# Why is my ForEach loops only returning one line?

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Midterm Review</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Tools Not Currently in Stock</h3>
        <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect(This part works );
            mysqli_select_db(this part works);
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `midterm` WHERE stock='0'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            echo '<table>';
            echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Part Number</th><th>Description</th><th>Stock</th><th>Price</th><th>Received</th></tr>';
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['part_number'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['stock'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['received_date'] . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                echo '</table>';
            };
            mysqli_close($conn);

        ?>
        <!--<form method="post" action="midterm_confirmation.php">
            <label>Part Number: </label><input type="text" name="partNumber" /><br />
            <label>Description: </label><input type="text" name="description" /></br />
            <label>Stock: </label><input type="number" name="stock" /><br />
            <label>Price: </label><input type="text" name ="price" /></br />
            <label>Received Date: </label><input type="text" name="receivedDate" /></br />
            <input type="Submit" value="Add to Stock">
            </form> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically my end result is that I am getting one table row, instead the two I am getting. Any suggestions? The table I have populates everything but is only running once, instead of posting for each line I have where stock is equal to zero.

Comment: should be: `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) { //echo each }`

Comment: Keep `</table>` outside the loop.

Comment: As regards the reason why this is happening - it's deceptive behaviour. Your `$result` is a resource, so when you loop it you will get one repetition. The `$row` call you have is converting to resource to actual data, which is why you're seeing data on that repetition. You've just got some of the methods in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

See the snippet below. P.S. Don't mix templates and database layer, it's a bad smell...

```
<?php
// establish connection to $conn variable

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `midterm` WHERE stock='0'");
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Part Number</th><th>Description</th><th>Stock</th><th>Price</th><th>Received</th></tr>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['part_number'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['stock'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['received_date'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in closing of `</table>` It should be kept outside the loop.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['part_number'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['stock'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['received_date'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    // echo '</table>';// this is wrong.
};
echo '</table>';// this is correct. closing table inside loop is wrong, do it outside the loop.
```

Comment: I didnt see them. May be they r answered when i was writing it.

Comment: Valid answer @SusheelSingh - no other answers have mentioned the closing table tag yet.

Comment: But that `html` is the main issue here.

Comment: but i have given him whats wrong, he can directly get his required output. no need to run again think of distorted values. Directly he canknow whats wrong in code.

Comment: if there is something wrong, and you noticed that, why dont u tell him what is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `while` loop to do it like below:

```
<?php
// establish connection to $conn    
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `midterm` WHERE stock='0'");
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Part Number</th><th>Description</th><th>Stock</th><th>Price</th><th>Received</th></tr>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['part_number'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['stock'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['received_date'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>'; // this should be outside the loop
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Or if you want to use a `foreach` then write an extra function for it:

```
<?php
function mysql_fetch_all($result) {
   $rows = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $rows[] = $row;
   }
   return $rows;
}


// establish connection to $conn
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `midterm` WHERE stock='0'");
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><th>ID</th><th>Part Number</th><th>Description</th><th>Stock</th><th>Price</th><th>Received</th></tr>';
foreach (mysql_fetch_all($result) as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['part_number'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['stock'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['received_date'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
} 
echo '</table>'; // this should be outside the loop
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```